# Video displaying two play buttons

Tags: html

Im using Html5 video tag for displaying small videos. When using video in desktop I have no issues (apparently). When accessing with mobile phone the video displays two play buttons. One big center and another one from controls. I just need one. Removing controls attribute removes both play buttons. How can I control which play button display?

My video tag is like follow:

```
<video class='pic-s' poster='{{this.images.thumbnail.url}}' controls preload='metadata'>
    <source src='{{this.videos.low_resolution.url}}' type='video/mp4; codecs='avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2'>
</video>
```

Data is retrieved from Instagram which only offers mp4 and so just once source. The result of applying this tag is this one for mobile phones:

[image]

Comment: you may hide controls, and create your own one.

Comment: Is that the only solution? I mean, there is no parameters available in video tag for configuring this behavior without building custom buttons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911247/hide-iphone-html5-video-play-button/
there is an answer to your question I think.