# Android HTML5 video issue

Tags: javascript, android, html, video

I am using HTML5 video tag to play an online video on Samsung tablet with android 5.0, but some issues come up. And it works fine on iOS.

```
 <video id='video-widget' autoplay='true'  preload autobuffer controls style="width:100%;">
        <source src="{{src}}">
    </video>


.video-widget-container {
    height: 469px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.video-widget-container video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button
    {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.video-widget-container video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    /*  display: block !important;
    -webkit-appearance:  button; */

}

.video-widget-container video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    /*      display: block !important;
    -webkit-appearance:  button;  */

}

.video-widget-container.loading video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
    {
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#video-widget.loading video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.video-widget-container video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button
    {
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.video-widget-container video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    /*  display: block !important;
     -webkit-appearance:  button; */

}



.video-widget-container video {
    background: transparent url('../images/video/CVE_MAP.svg') no-repeat 0 0;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

1. the video does not autoplay although I have set autoplay;
2. there is an ugly big play button along with the poster I set, as seen in the picture1 the world map is my poster ;
3. how can I hide the default play button in code ?

[image: picture 1]

Comment: Maybe this is the answer you are looking for ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911247/hide-iphone-html5-video-play-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the poster's issue. I think if the poster is not set in code. The webview would set a default one for the video tag. So I set the value of poster as 'null'. It is ok.

Comment: Setting null did not work for me. Adding a transparent 1px png did the trick though!

Answer (score -1):

I am successfully playing video on `Android` `4.2.2`, `4.3`, `4.4.4`, `5.0`, `5.1`.
solution:

- Install crosswalk
- Tell angular to trust the URL `$scope.vidURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data.vidURL);`
- Wrap the video element in a div with `data-tap-disable="true"`