# Can we hide media controls from WebView while playing Video in it?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have to show playing video in `GridView` and I am using `WebView` to show video but the problem is that media controls are visible. Can we hide/disable these media controls from `WebView`? or
can we restrict to `WebView` to show only thumbnail instead of playing video.

I am using WebView in `GridView` because `VideoView` and `TextureView`  takes lots of time to load and I when scroll up/down app get freezes. 
Please suggest. 
Thank You.

Comment: A useful link for you - Hide HTML5 video play button (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911247/hide-iphone-html5-video-play-button)

Comment: Thanks @AnkitNeoGHz I m going to try it.