# videogular2 set next video and play automatically

Tags: angular, ionic2, videogular

I made simple player in ionic 2 with videogular-2. When i press start button first video is playing X number of time after getting end event i play video again for X time. For example first.mp4 is playing 2 time after i will set next video in source of videogular video is set successfully but next loaded video is not playing automatically. If i press play button video plays.

### html

```
<ion-content>

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col text-center>
            <h3>First > Second > Third > Fourth > Fifth > Sixth > Seventh</h3>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1>
        {{duration}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11>
            <button ion-button (click)="playVideo()" [hidden]="isPlaying">Start Workout</button>

            <vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)" [hidden]="!isPlaying">
                <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
                <video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" crossorigin>
                    <source *ngFor="let video of sources" [src]="video.src" [type]="video.type">
                </video>
            </vg-player>
        </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

### ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgControlsModule } from 'videogular2/controls';
import { VgOverlayPlayModule } from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
import { VgBufferingModule } from 'videogular2/buffering';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage 
{
    isPlaying : any;
    duration : any;
    sources : Array<Object>;
    api:VgAPI;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) 
    {
        this.isPlaying = false;

        this.sources = new Array<Object>();
        this.sources.push({
          src: "small.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        });

        //this.setCurrentVideo("small.mp4","video/mp4");
    }
    setCurrentVideo(source : string, type : string) 
    {
        this.sources = new Array<Object>();
        this.sources.push({
          src: source,
          type: type
        });
        this.api.getDefaultMedia().currentTime = 0;
    }
    onPlayerReady(api:VgAPI) 
    {
        var x = 1;
        this.api = api;

        this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.ended.subscribe(
            () => 
            {
                x++;
                if(x>2)
                {
                    this.setCurrentVideo("SampleVideo_1280x720_2mb.mp4","video/mp4");
                    x = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.api.play();
                }
            }
        );

    }
    playVideo()
    {
        this.isPlaying = true;
        this.api.play();
        this.duration = Math.ceil((this.api.duration * 5));
    }   
}
```

After setting next video using this line

```
this.setCurrentVideo("SampleVideo_1280x720_2mb.mp4","video/mp4");
```

i tried `this.api.play();` but they give error like below

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().
```

Comment: Can you try this demo on a mobile? https://videogular.github.io/videogular2-showroom/#/smart-playlist I think that you can't autoplay on some mobile devices, that depends on the OS. Since iOS10 you can autoplay only if you set mute attribute and playsinline. You have more info here: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: @elecash Thanks for your answer i will try and let you know about that.

Comment: @elecash Thanks that is working fine but issue is when we switch between 2 videos display big play button any solution of that?

Comment: I think that you need to hide it through css https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911247/hide-iphone-html5-video-play-button

Comment: @elecash i can hide it using css? wow amazing..! Thanks you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fix that following way i dont known that is proper or not.

### html

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col text-center>
        <h3>First > Second > Third > Fourth > Fifth > Sixth > Seventh</h3>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1>
    {{duration}}
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11>
        <button ion-button (click)="playVideo()" id="myButton" [hidden]="isPlaying">Start Workout</button>

        <vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)" [hidden]="!isPlaying">
            <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
            <video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" crossorigin>
                <source *ngFor="let video of sources" [src]="video.src" [type]="video.type">
            </video>
        </vg-player>
    </ion-col>

</ion-row>
```

### js

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgControlsModule } from 'videogular2/controls';
import { VgOverlayPlayModule } from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
import { VgBufferingModule } from 'videogular2/buffering';
import * as $ from 'jquery'

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage 
{
    isPlaying : any;
    duration : any;
    sources : Array<Object>;
    api:VgAPI;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) 
    {
        this.isPlaying = false;

        this.sources = new Array<Object>();
        this.sources.push({
          src: "small.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        });

        //this.setCurrentVideo("small.mp4","video/mp4");
    }
    setCurrentVideo(source : string, type : string) 
    {
        this.sources = new Array<Object>();
        this.sources.push({
          src: source,
          type: type
        });
        this.api.getDefaultMedia().currentTime = 0;
    }
    onPlayerReady(api:VgAPI) 
    {
        var x = 1;
        this.api = api;

        this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.ended.subscribe(
            () => 
            {
                x++;
                if(x>2)
                {
                    this.setCurrentVideo("SampleVideo_1280x720_2mb.mp4","video/mp4");

                    this.onPlayerReady(this.api);

                    setTimeout(function () 
                    {
                        $("#myButton").trigger( "click" );    
                    },1000);


                    x = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.api.play();
                }
            }
        );

    }
    playVideo()
    {
        this.isPlaying = true;
        this.api.play();
        this.duration = Math.ceil((this.api.duration * 5));
    }

}
```