# How to disable native ios video player buttons?

Tags: ios, css, video

Because of IOS 11 i have a problem where two video player bars are visible. Is there any way to remove or hide the one which is white fanced(native player) ? This happen only in IOS 11 when you turn on the video on full screen and  make a rainbow swipe gesture on the screen from side to side. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide iPhone HTML5 video play button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911247/hide-iphone-html5-video-play-button)

Comment: it does not work for me