# Video element in HTML shows large play button on certain browsers

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser

I have an html element

```
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay">Video stream not available.</video>
```

and js

```
 const video = document.getElementById('video');
 video.play()
 video.style.display = 'block'
 video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
 video.setAttribute('muted', '');
 video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
```

It works on every browser but if I open link from SKYPE it doesn't work.

[image: some browsers returns this instead of video]

Comment: Possible dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/q/8911247/1746830

Comment: When you open it from Skype what browser does it open in?

Comment: idk which browser is it